# How to pass data from one child to parent and other child components?

Tags: angular5

I have divided my page into following format. I have a parent component and multiple child components. First one being the filter component. So when I make a submit in this component its result is to be implemented in all other child component as well as in parent component too.

I think of as the date I receive from child-A to parent component pass it to child-B and child-C but I couldn't fix it.

I am working here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqp5px

Can anybody help me on this?

Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create simple service and pass value to Subject object. And subscribe that object in other component where ever you want to make use of it.

For example service:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class dataService {
    //here i am giving example for string. You can use any kind of object(class)
    private querySource = new Subject<string>();
    query$ = this.querySource.asObservable();

    functionname(value: string){
               this.querySource.next(value);
     }
}
```

Now subscribe this service and call functionName function on submit button. And the change will be subscribed where ever you want it in parent or any other child component.

For refrence go through [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject)

Comment: but for some reason I could not reset. can you pls check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqp5px